# Firebase auth with multiple apps in a project

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, access-token

I have a firebase project with two apps in it. Client App and Service provider app. Both use firebase phone authentication. 
every user can register as a client or Service provider which the same phone number. 
On the server side, I can get the user id (which is the same for both apps), from the token (which is different for each app) that has been send. The thing that I don't know how to retrieve is the token belongs to the user in which app? 
For example when the app sends a request to the server to get the profile info of the logged in user, it sends the token to the server. Now how can I find out if I should return the user profile info for the Client app or Service provider app. Which are two very different profile models.

Comment: You can have separate root elements for both the apps. In each app refer to the `approot/uid` element where `approot` is the app from which the user is accessing the database. Since, your profile model is different for both the apps, this shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: @MayankVerma I did the same. `/client/profile/id` and `/provider/profile/id` are the routes to get the profile for each app. I thought maybe there is a way to get the app in which the token has been generated

Comment: So what if you achieve what you wanted? What difference does it make? In my opinion, you will still have to maintain separate elements for different apps.

Comment: @MayankVerma because from the client side I have to send the `appType` in every request, additional to `token`. When I be able to retrieve the app type from the token there will be no need to send the `appType` with every request

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use custom user claims to differentiate users from client app or service provider app: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims

You would set the custom claims using the Firebase Admin SDK:

```
admin.auth().setCustomUserClaims(uid, {role: 'client'|'provider'})
```

You would enforce access in your rules. For example:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "providerContent": {
      ".read": "auth.token.role === 'provider'",
      ".write": "auth.token.role === 'provider'",
    },
    "clientContent": {
      ".read": "auth.token.role === 'client'",
      ".write": "auth.token.role === 'client'",
    }
  }
}
```

You can propagate your claims as follows:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims#propagate_custom_claims_to_the_client

You would need to force refresh the token on the client side.

Comment: I'll try it and let you know

Comment: It seems from iOS device, I can't access admin SDK. If true, then I can't set custom role for authenticated user from client side, then I won't be able to check it from the server side. Any tips?

Comment: Admin SDK can only be access from a backend server. It should not be used from a client side device. You would need to send a request to your server with some proof before setting the role on your server via the admin SDK. For example after sign in from the provider app, you send the ID token and some flag (eg. "provider" to your server) that the request is coming from the provider app, verify the ID token and then set that role to that user's associated `uid`. This is the naive way of doing it.

Comment: I get the authenticated user from client side with this method: `            Auth.auth().signIn(with: credential) { (user, error) in` for both existing users and new user. How is it possible to differ if an existing user is singed in or Firebase has created a new user and then signed in the user?

Comment: Use the latest version with `signInAndRetrieveDataWithCredential:completion:`. It returns a `AuthDataResultCallback` which provides you a `AdditionalUserInfo` which has a `newUser` Bool on whether the user is new or existing: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebaseauth/api/reference/Classes/AdditionalUserInfo#newuser